# How can I see which script is being executed by sails lift?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm working on a project built by someone else using Sails.js (which is a pretty new technology for me).

The problem I'm having is that for every little change I make to the code I have to restart the server, which is obviously very time consuming. Some articles I read mention the use of `forever`, which I have installed. The problem I have is that the project I'm working on doesn't have an `app.js` file in it's root directory.

Following the documentation for Sails and the examples of how to build a test application, I figured there should be an `app.js` file in the root directory of the project, so I'm kind of confused.

When I run `sails lift` everything works fine, but I can't figure out how to start my server in a forever fashion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

according to this:

http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/app.js.html

there should be an app.js, otherwise you cant run it.
On your left hand side there is a filetree, and it shows where it should be located.
Sure it isn't there?

Comment: I'm sure. That's the whole problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the app.js file is hidden in the OS? did you try to run it from CLI?
Or try to search the whole directory for `sails.lift`,i use linux so I would use searchmonkey or something like that

Comment: Thanks... I've tried looking for the file, but nothing turned up... I've tried using --verbose on sails lift but didn't find anything useful

Comment: Some text file has to contain the sails.lift command or that command would not work, so I would search for that string in all text files within the folder by some program

Comment: Ok, I run a search for that text and the only reference I found was ./node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js... should I use that file as the starting point for forever?

Comment: You could try, but I am afraid it will not work. Thats the file where sails lift is defined, but its not the file which runs the custom sails app.
This is indeed quite peculiar, Im afraid your last option is to contact the person who built this particular sails app and ask wth did he do to it :D

Comment: hehe, that was my first choice... but that knowledge kind of got lost in cyberspace :(. Thanks anyway!